# Center two css divs with variable width in a div with fixed with

Tags: css, html, dynamic, width, center

I am trying now since hours, nothing helps.
Just simple:
I have two divs with variable (dynamic) width.
Both should be side by side in a wrapper div, that has a fixed width.
Everything I try: I see leftDiv and rightDiv either floating to the left or centered, but div2 under div1.... Thanks a lot.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <div class='innerWrapper'>
      <div class='leftDiv'>
      </div>
      <div class='rightDiv'>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What is the correct css? The problem is, that it does not work to give the innerWrapper automatically the width of both divs (leftDiv and rightDiv...)...

I tried:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}

.innerWrapper {
    width: auto;
}

.leftDiv {
    display: inline-block;
}

.rightDiv {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please include the CSS you have tried.

Comment: specify which browser you need this for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` on those divs ..

http://jsfiddle.net/RK6R4/